# Can't get cdrecord to work on new 13.04 installation

Tags: 13.04, burning

Just upgraded a laptop to 13.04. Via Brasero, I can burn CDs and DVDs, but when I try `cdrecord` from the command line I get:

```
$ cdrecord --devices
wodim: No such file or directory. 
Cannot open SCSI driver!
For possible targets try 'wodim --devices' or 'wodim -scanbus'.
For possible transport specifiers try 'wodim dev=help'.
For IDE/ATAPI devices configuration, see the file README.ATAPI.setup from
the wodim documentation.
```

I get that same error regardless of the parameters with which I invoke the command. Is there some sort of package dependency issue?

*edit* — running `wodim` with `strace` shows that it tries to open all the drives `/dev/hda` through `/dev/hdz`, then everything from `/dev/scd0` through `/dev/scd255`, and then it quits.  It's probably a configuration thing.

Comment: What does: ls -l /dev/sg1 show?

Comment: @konrad it's there. The thing is, `wodim` never tries to open that pathname. It tries all the `/dev/hd` paths and all the `/dev/scd` paths it can think of and quits. I'll update the question.

Comment: What about the permission on the device? Mine is: crw-rw----+ 1 root cdrom 21, 1 May  9 09:03 /dev/sg1

Comment: Same - plus I was running su'd to a root shell.  Like I said, it doesn't matter because the program never attempts to open that device anyway.

Answer (score 5):

As [@braiam mentioned](https://askubuntu.com/a/351459/17531) this would appear to be a known issue with `wodim`. As a workaround you can use `wodim -prcap` instead.

```
$ wodim -prcap
wodim: Operation not permitted. Warning: Cannot raise RLIMIT_MEMLOCK limits.
Device was not specified. Trying to find an appropriate drive...
Detected CD-R drive: /dev/sr0
Using /dev/cdrom of unknown capabilities
Device type    : Removable CD-ROM
Version        : 5
Response Format: 2
Capabilities   : 
Vendor_info    : 'Optiarc '
Identification : 'DVD RW AD-7930H '
Revision       : '1.D1'
Device seems to be: Generic mmc2 DVD-R/DVD-RW.

Drive capabilities, per MMC-3 page 2A:

  Does read CD-R media
  Does write CD-R media
  Does read CD-RW media
  Does write CD-RW media
  Does read DVD-ROM media
  Does read DVD-R media
  Does write DVD-R media
  Does read DVD-RAM media
  Does write DVD-RAM media
  Does support test writing

  Does read Mode 2 Form 1 blocks
  Does read Mode 2 Form 2 blocks
...
```

Answer (score 2):

I believe [this is a bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/cdrkit/+bug/1203559).

The workaround is to specify the device manually or in /etc/wodim.conf:

```
wodim dev=/dev/sr0 --devices
```

Off course, listing the devices while specifying the device is a bit silly but with this option I'm able to write a CD.

Note this is on 12.04 but should apply to your version as well.